# Adaptabilidad de la página según el dispositivo y la legilibidad del usuario

Tags: oracle, apex

[oracle-apex](/questions/tagged/oracle-apex) [oracle-plsql](/questions/tagged/oracle-plsql)

Cuál sería la forma más acorde a Oracle Apex de colocar un botón de zoom-in, zoom-out en la página que actúe sobre todos los elementos que contengan texto y en consecuencia, se redimensiones grillas, justificado derecho, etc?

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y leas [ask] y además agregues un [example]. Qué has intentado hasta el momento? Este tipo de preguntas suele estar basada en opiniones y no se ajusta a las reglas del sitio. Te recomiendo que especifiques el error puntual que estás teniendo

Comment: ¿Por qué no usar el zoom del navegador?

Comment: El zoom del navegador amplía todo el contenido, agranda botones, etc... se necesita que sólo se aumente un poco el tamaño de la letra para gente con problemas de visión. Además el zoom deja los botones fuera del área de visualización y en realidad se quiere que al aumentar el tamaño de la letra los botones continúen quedando en su lugar. Ejemplo: Si tengo un botón alineado hacia la derecha, al hacer zoom quedará fuera del área visible y no se quiere eso. La página debe realmente adaptarse.